# Time series clustering for a dataframe

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have a data frame with multiple ids which have their own time series data. Here, I only provide a simple example. I would like to cluster them into 2 (in real data 10) classes. I have tried to use the time series clustering in [this tutorial](https://github.com/mihagrabner/Clustering-Smart-Meter-Data-tutorial), however it does not work for me (since it has time and etc.) Could you help me with that? Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df ['value_1'] = [2, 3, 4, 6]
df ['value_2'] = [5,1, 4, 6]
df ['value_3'] = [2, 2, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You case use GMM for clustering or advanced ml algorithms like TICC. whose clusters are formed based on different distribution/patterns.

Catch here is you don't feed "time" feature while training. TICC treats each time as a one state. You can find more details in this paper: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/ticc-kdd17.pdf

Thanks, Hope this was helpful. :)